# Open a link to new tab inside a ifame of iframe

Tags: html, facebook

I have a `iframe-1` and it contains another `iframe-1-1`.<sup>**[1]**</sup>
Inside `iframe-1-1` which contains a link.
When a user click the link:

> It should open a new tab (For instance, Firebug/or Chrome).<sup>**[2]**</sup>

But it does not work. How can I do that?

---

**[1]** Why I have this question: because I code a webpage, it is embedded in Facebook, and I call FB.dialog it will show me a dialog is a iframe too.
**[2]** It works properly if I use wheel button to click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't instruct a browser to open a new tab. The best you can do is to use `target="_blank"` and hope that the user is using a browser that will open a tab and not a new window.

Comment: Why not? You are out of luck then, unless you can use JavaScript to add it to your links ...

Comment: You can not add the script code into a iframe which does not belong to you. (iframe is generated by FB API)